# Best way to style cakephp app

Tags: cakephp

I've got a template X and I want this to become the default style.  Meaning I don't want to do this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('class'=>'form-control'));?>
```

I want to just do this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('phone');
```

Do I edit the FormHelper, create a new helper, or do I rewrite the styles in cake's style.css with the those from template X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and cleanest way is to override the `FormHelper`. So you create a new helper, and then in the respective controllers you can add:

```
public $helpers = array('Form' => array('className' => 'newFormHelper'));
```

Look here for more references: http://blog.nlware.com/2012/02/07/cakephp-2-0-how-to-extend-the-formhelper/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify inputDefaults in your create method.

```
$this->Form->create('Model', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control'
    )
);
```

There are more options you could use if you wish, it sounds like this is for bootstrap so you might want to checkout BoostCake

https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake